# How to replace json with the one from the master branch

Tags: php, json, git, opencart2.x

I'm not programmer and I don't know coding.

I use opencart 2.1.0.1. I cannot access "customer/customer", "customer/customer groups", "customer/custom fields" page it said "You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator". Well I'm the only administrator.

All access permission has been selected from settings but I didn't see customer/customer, customer/customer groups and customer/custom fields from permission listings.

So Daniel Kerr suggest me to replace json with the one from master branch.

I replace system/helper/json.php with the code from this link [Branch Master for json.php][1]

I edited json.php by using putty.

But still cannot access customer page. Please someone guide me how to replace json with master branch.

Comment: Code from this link : https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/helper/json.php

Comment: Where you get error "permision denied"? You get it from web browser or from computer (when you open file for viewing/editing)? It's a major detail.

Comment: And why did you decide that the problem in the file json.php?

Comment: I got it from web browser when trying to access customer/customer, customer/customer group and customer/custom fields.

Comment: Ok, look my last answer, check that you did all correctly. I think the problem in your .htaccess file (did you renamed default htaccess.txt sample to .htaccess? what you put to this file?), but privilegies for the scripts may calling this error too.

Answer (score 0):

To get code from another branch you have 2 options. One is to check out that one file.

Got checkout master -- /path/to/file.json

The other is to use git show

Git show master:path/to/file.json  > path/to/file.json

The first option is probably the preferred one

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that used folders has a insufficient privileges. Try `chmod -R 777` for /var/www/your_project folder. I think your problem is in the lack of privileges for the project files.

If it will not help, check your .htaccess file and allow/deny rules (if you getting "access denied" from web browser). See https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/.htaccess.txt and don't ignore this rules by file (maybe you didn't):

> # 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled.
>
> # 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.
>
> # For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solutions. There are missing files in /www/my_project folder. Recovered the missing customer.php files and resolved! Thanks everyone